# Text to cleaner text to excel spreadsheet project

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I have a text file full of pc data, organized as a list of blocks of one of two types. Either:

```
*redacted*
```

My goal was to have Python (3.6.2) open and read the file, clean it up, and compile the data into an excel spreadsheet as follows:

```
Column 1: PC name 
Column 2: Error Type (0 if none, 1-4 for 4 error types)
Column 3: ID (if no error, no braces containing the ID)
Column 4: Password (if no error, just the password)
```

Here is my code. I use Pycharm, and am in a virtual env:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Computer Data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
left = workbook.add_format({'align': 'justify'})

worksheet.set_column(0, 0, 14)
worksheet.set_column(1, 1, 5)
worksheet.set_column(2, 2, 38)
worksheet.set_column(3, 3, 55)

worksheet.write('A1', 'Name', bold)
worksheet.write('B1', 'Error', bold)
worksheet.write('C1', 'ID', bold)
worksheet.write('D1', 'Password', bold)

def nonblank_lines(f):
    for l in f:
        line = l.rstrip()
        if line:
            yield line.lstrip

with open("C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\BLRP.txt", "r+") as op:
    gold_lst = []
    nonblank = nonblank_lines(op)
    for line in nonblank:
        if line.startswith("Computer Name"):
            gold_lst.append(str(line))
            gold_lst.append("NO ERROR")
        elif line.startswith("ID"):
            gold_lst.append("IDG: " + str(line))
            gold_lst.append('NO ERROR')
        elif line.startswith("ERROR: An error occurred while"):
            gold_lst.append('1')
            gold_lst.append(str('ID: {' + line + '}'))
            gold_lst.append(str('Password: '))
        elif line.startswith("ERROR: No key"):
            gold_lst.append('2')
            gold_lst.append(str('ID: {' + line + '}'))
            gold_lst.append(str('Password: '))
        elif line.startswith("ERROR: An error occurred (code 0x80070057)"):
            gold_lst.append('3')
            gold_lst.append(str('ID: {' + line + '}'))
            gold_lst.append(str('Password: '))
        elif line.startswith("ERROR: An error occurred (code 0x8004100e)"):
            gold_lst.append('4')
            gold_lst.append(str('ID: {' + line + '}'))
            gold_lst.append(str('Password: '))
        elif line.startswith("Password"):
            gold_lst.append(str('Password: ' + next(nonblank)))
    print(gold_lst)
    op.close()

pc_data = (gold_lst)

row = 1
col = 0

for obj in pc_data:
    if obj.startswith("Computer Name"):
        worksheet.write_string(row, col, obj[15:])
    elif obj.startswith('NO'):
        worksheet.write_number(row, col + 1, 0, left)
    elif obj.startswith('1'):
        worksheet.write_number(row, col + 1, int(obj), left)
    elif obj.startswith('2'):
        worksheet.write_number(row, col + 1, int(obj), left)
    elif obj.startswith('3'):
        worksheet.write_number(row, col + 1, int(obj), left)
    elif obj.startswith('4'):
        worksheet.write_number(row, col + 1, int(obj), left)
    elif obj.startswith("ID: {ERROR"):
        worksheet.write_string(row, col + 2, '')
    elif obj.startswith("IDG: "):
        worksheet.write_string(row, col + 2, obj[10:-1])
    elif obj.startswith("Password"):
        worksheet.write_string(row, col + 3, obj[9:]) 
        row += 1

workbook.close()
```

Now, this works perfectly for the file in question, but, in addition to the terribly suboptimal code, I'm sure, there is something I can explicitly see that needs improved. In this block:

```
if line.startswith("Computer Name"):
                gold_lst.append(str(line))
                gold_lst.append("NO ERROR")
```

I only want "NO ERROR" to be appended to my list if my line starts with "Computer Name" AND the next non-blank line does not begin with "ERROR." Naturally, I tried this:

```
if line.startswith("Computer Name"):
        if next(nonblank).startswith("ERROR"):
            gold_lst.append(str(line))
        elif next(nonblank).startswith("VOLUME"):
            gold_lst.append(str(line))
            gold_lst.append("NO ERROR")
```

The problem is, this creates a jacked up excel spreadsheet, *and I don't at all know why.* Even in the step afterward in the main code where I print gold_lst (just to check if the list is correct), the list is terribly inaccurate. I can't even seem to figure out of what the list is comprised.

*How can I fix this?*

As for a second question, if I may ask it in the same topic, more general text files of this type which I am likely to receive in the future may contain computers with more than one ID and password. The block would look like this, if I had to guess:

```
*redacted*
```

And there may be even more than 2 such ID/Password combos. *How can I modify my code to allow for this?* As it stands, my code will not easily account for this. I am quite new to Python, so maybe it could, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to this problem is as follows:

1. Read in the whole file, skipping any empty lines.
2. Use Python's [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby) function to split the list of lines into blocks based on the `Computer Name` line.
3. For each block, try and extract both an error and a list of IDs and Passwords. Leave blank if not present.
4. For each block, write any extracted data to the next row in the spreadsheet.

The script is as follows:

```
from itertools import groupby
import xlsxwriter
import re

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Computer Data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
left = workbook.add_format({'align': 'justify'})
cols = [('Name', 14), ('Error', 5), ('ID1', 38), ('Password1', 55), ('ID2', 38), ('Password2', 55), ('ID3', 38), ('Password3', 55)]

for colx, (heading, width) in enumerate(cols):
    worksheet.write_string(0, colx, heading, bold)
    worksheet.set_column(colx, colx, width)

rowy = 1
lines = []
data = []
computer_name = None

with open('BLRP.txt') as f_input:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f_input if len(line.strip())]

for k, g in groupby(lines, lambda x: x.startswith("Computer Name:")):
    if k:
        computer_name = re.search(r'Computer Name:\s*(.*)\s*', list(g)[0]).group(1)
    elif computer_name:
        block = list(g)
        error = 'NO ERROR'
        ids = []
        passwords = []

        for line_number, line in enumerate(block):
            re_error = re.match('ERROR:\s+"(.*?)"', line)

            if re_error:
                error = re_error.group(1)

            if line.startswith('Numerical Password:'):
                ids.append(re.search('\{(.*?)\}', block[line_number+1]).group(1))
                passwords.append(block[line_number+3].strip())

        worksheet.write_string(rowy, 0, computer_name)
        worksheet.write_string(rowy, 1, error)

        for index, (id, pw) in enumerate(zip(ids, passwords)):
            worksheet.write_string(rowy, index * 2 + 2, id)
            worksheet.write_string(rowy, index * 2 + 3, pw)

        rowy += 1   # Advance to the next output row

workbook.close()
```

Assuming your `BLRP.txt` is as follows:

```
Computer Name: "Name Here1"

ERROR: "some type of error"

Blah blah
Blah blah
Blah blah

Computer Name: "Name Here2"

Volume blah blah
Blah Blah

         Numerical Password:
            ID: {"The ID1 is here; long string of random chars"}
              Password:
                "Password1 here; also a long string"

Blah Blah
Blah Blah

         Numerical Password:
            ID: {"The ID2 is here; long string of random chars"}
              Password:
                "Password2 here; also a long string"

Blah Blah
Blah Blah

         Numerical Password:
            ID: {"The ID3 is here; long string of random chars"}
              Password:
                "Password3 here; also a long string"

Blah Blah
Blah Blah
```

You would get a spreadsheet as follows:

[image: Spreadsheet screenshot]

**How does `groupby()` work?**

Normally when you iterate over a list, it gives you the entries one item at a time. With `groupby()`, you are able to iterate over this list in "groups", where the number of items in each group is based on a condition. The condition is provided in the form of a function (I have used `lambda` to avoid writing a separate function).

`groupby()` will build up the group of items to return until the result from the function changes. In this case, the function is looking for lines that start with the word `Computer Name`. So when that is true it will return with one item (unless there are two adjacent lines with `Computer Name` on them). Next it will return with all the lines that don't start with `Computer Name`, and so on.

It returns two things, a `key` and a `group`. The `key` is the result of the function `startswith()`, which will either be `True` or `False`. The `group` is an iterable holding all the matching items. `list(g)` is used to convert it into a normal list, in this case all the lines until the next `Computer Name` line is returned.

---

To write the entries onto different rows and to convert known error messages into numbers:

```
from itertools import groupby
import xlsxwriter
import re

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Computer Data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
left = workbook.add_format({'align': 'justify'})
cols = [('Name', 14), ('Error', 5), ('ID', 38), ('Password', 55)]

for colx, (heading, width) in enumerate(cols):
    worksheet.write_string(0, colx, heading, bold)
    worksheet.set_column(colx, colx, width)

rowy = 1
lines = []
data = []
computer_name = None

error_numbers = {
    'An error occurred while connecting to the BitLocker management interface.' : 1, 
    'No key protectors found.' : 2, 
    'An error occurred (code 0x80070057):' : 3,
    'An error occurred (code 0x8004100e):' : 4}

with open('BLRP.txt') as f_input:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f_input if len(line.strip())]

for k, g in groupby(lines, lambda x: x.startswith("Computer Name:")):
    block = list(g)

    if k:
        computer_name = re.search(r'Computer Name:\s*(.*)\s*', block[0]).group(1)
    elif computer_name:
        error_number = 0        # 0 for NO ERROR
        ids = []
        passwords = []

        for line_number, line in enumerate(block):
            re_error = re.match('ERROR:\s+?(.*)\s*?', line)

            if re_error:
                error = re_error.group(1)
                error_number = error_numbers.get(error, -1)     # Return -1 for an unknown error

            if line.startswith('Numerical Password:'):
                ids.append(re.search('\{(.*?)\}', block[line_number+1]).group(1))
                passwords.append(block[line_number+3].strip())

        worksheet.write_string(rowy, 0, computer_name)
        worksheet.write_number(rowy, 1, error_number)

        for id, pw in zip(ids, passwords):
            worksheet.write_string(rowy, 0, computer_name)
            worksheet.write_number(rowy, 1, error_number)
            worksheet.write_string(rowy, 2, id)
            worksheet.write_string(rowy, 3, pw)
            rowy += 1   # Advance to the next output row

        if len(ids) == 0:
            rowy += 1   # Advance to the next output row            

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand most of what's going on as soon as you start your "groupby," even after reading the documentation. What are k and g referring to? What is your groupby producing? What does the next "if k" mean?

Comment: I should also mention I messed up in the description of the text files: there are no quotation marks around the passwords, IDs, or computer names.

Comment: I have added a short explanation on `groupby()`, it is a very useful function to learn about. I have also made a change to stop it looking for quotation marks. If you are ever not sure about something, add a `print()` statement into the script to see what something looks like.

Comment: Your groupby() explanation makes perfect sense. Thank you for your reply. I have some other small questions: first, what exactly is the computer_name variable storing? And what is the 'r' before the 'Computer Name: etc' representing? Speaking of this, when I run your code, I get an error saying computer_name is not defined. I assume this is because it's a local variable. Lastly, it seems you're still searching for quotation marks in your re_error variable.

Comment: Oh! What is your data list accomplishing?

Comment: It was not needed. I have removed itm

Comment: Please see the comment prior to the one asking about your data list. Your code will not execute for me due to computer_name, and I don't understand your use of grouping. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you have tested the current script? I had updated it work better with the computer name.

Comment: I tested the exact script, and it doesn't like the variable computer_name being used in the write_string command, since you're defining computer_name as a local variable under "if k." I also still don't see what you're .group(1) is doing in the definition of the computer_name variable, nor do I understand why there is an 'r' before 'Computer Name.' Here is the line, for reference: 
computer_name = re.search(r'Computer Name:\s*(.*)\s*', list(g)[0]).group(1)

Comment: The exact error:  File "C:/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/StackTest.py", line 41, in <module>
    worksheet.write_string(rowy, 0, computer_name)
NameError: name 'computer_name' is not defined
Exception ignored in: <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x0000000002A93128>>
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: The file you were testing probably did not start with `Computer Name:`. The script should now skip lines until that first entry is found.

Comment: So, the code works now, but I can't say I understand it. You set computer_name to None before running groupby, but then you're checking elif: computer_name, meaning elif None, and then writing computer_name to the current row in column 0, which to me interprets to you writing None to that row, yet that's not what happens.

Comment: Glad it is working. It is designed to ignore all lines until it finds a computer name. It then starts parsing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153052/discussion-between-johnny-apple-and-martin-evans).

Comment: Is there a way to mark the error column as D  for all instances beyond the first of a given computer name?